# single sign in/out not working on rubycas-server

Tags: django, ruby-on-rails-3, cas, rubycas

i had enabled enable_single_sign_out: true.

I have two application, one in Rails, other in Django,

I want that when i login to one application, i would just go an refresh my other application and i would signed in automatically.

Sam way, if i singout from one application, and refresh other application i would sign out from it also.

How to implement this scenario with rubycas-server.

Currently when i login to one application and go to second and just click on login, it will automatically login. But i have to explicitly logout both applications separately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Django client (the rubycas-server docs say that currently not all client applications support single sign out) but in order to get the Ruby CAS client to support single sign out you need to do the following (in the client app):

1. The Rails session store must be set to ActiveRecord:
   `config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store`
2. The server must be able to read and write to RAILS_ROOT/tmp/sessions. If you are in a clustered environment, the contents of this directory must be shared between all server instances.
3. Cross-site request forgery protection must be disabled. In your application.rb: `self.allow_forgery_protection = false`. (Or rather you may want to disable forgery protection only for actions that are behind the CAS filter.)

Further information can be found here: https://github.com/gunark/rubycas-client#readme